# SQL select row IF condition satisfied Otherwise find a row with max Date

Tags: sql, group-by, case

I have the following data structure

```
Date1         |  Date2               | a      | b
2018-11-15    |  2010-11-15          | 1      | null
2018-11-15    |  2011-11-15          | 0      | 300
2018-11-15    |  2012-11-15          | 0      | 100

2018-11-14    |  2010-11-15          | 1      | 200
2018-11-14    |  2012-11-15          | 0      | 100

2018-11-13    |  2010-11-15          | 1      | null
2018-11-13    |  2011-11-15          | 0      | 100
```

For each unique Date1 I need to

- select row with a = 1  (there is only 1 of such row) if b is not null
- otherwise find a row with Date2 being maximum (doesn't matter b is null or not).

So ideally I would like to get

```
Date1         |  Date2               | a      | b
2018-11-15    |  2012-11-15          | 0      | 100
2018-11-14    |  2010-11-15          | 1      | 200
2018-11-13    |  2011-11-15          | 0      | 100
```

I assume I need to combine Group BY Date1 and CASE THEN conditions but could figure out how that should work. 
Appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` with conditional ordering:

```
select date1, date2, a, b
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by date1 
            order by 
                case when a = 1 and b is not null then 0 else 1 end, 
                date2 desc, 
                b desc
            ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

It is quite unclear whether you want to partition by just `date1` or `date1` *and* `date2`. Since you said you want the record with max `date2`, I assumed that you want partitions of `date1` and a sorting criteria on `date2 desc`.

Finally, I added a third sorting criteria `b desc` to try and make the results (more) predictable if there are ties in the first two criterias.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want partition by date1 and a sorting on date2 (so your second guess). When I run your query it returns only a=1 rows so doesn't fulfill the conditions of not having b = null ...

Comment: @Hamed: ah yes, I misread that part of your question. I just modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves my problem. I had to make a small modification to your answer since when a =1 and b is null the date2 is max by definition in my data structure and your query still would pick that row. so I had to add one line in your "order by" to take care of this :  case when a =1 and b is not null then 0 when a = 0 and b is not null then 1 else 2 end, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with UNION ALL and NOT EXISTS:

```
select * from tablename
where a = 1 and b is not null
union all
select t.* from tablename t
where 
  not exists (
    select 1 from tablename 
    where date1 = t.date1 and (date2 > t.date2 or (a = 1 and b is not null))
  )
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vS7gbheb6qHTdqB8NYuDzW/0).
Results:

```
| Date1               | Date2               | a   | b   |
| ------------------- | ------------------- | --- | --- |
| 2018-11-15 00:00:00 | 2012-11-15 00:00:00 | 0   | 100 |
| 2018-11-14 00:00:00 | 2010-11-15 00:00:00 | 1   | 200 |
| 2018-11-13 00:00:00 | 2011-11-15 00:00:00 | 0   | 100 |
```